# Which of the following staements are true (NBHM-$2014$)

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in \mathrm{GL}\,_n(\mathbb R)$ have integer entries. Let  $b \in \mathbb R^n $ be a column vector also with integer entries. Then

1. If $Ax = b$ , then entries of $x$ are also integers.
2. if $Ax = b$ , then the entries of $x$ are rational.
3. The matrix $A^{-1}$  has integer entries  iff  $\det(A) = \pm 1$.

For (1)  is false  by Cramer's Rule.

For (2)  is true by Cramer Rule.

For (3), I think it is also true.

Thank you for sparing your valuable time in checking my solutions

Comment: What is NBHM-2014?

Comment: $NBHM$ means national board of higher mathematics which is conducted an exam for phd programme in INDIA

Comment: They all seem correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are right. Since ${A^{ - 1}}$ has integer entries, $det({A^{-1}})=det(A)^{-1}$ is an integer. It's true only for neither $det(A)$ is 1 or -1. By the formula ${A^{ - 1}} = \frac{{{A^ * }}}{{\det \left( A \right)}}$, the other hand holds.